# How to configure proxmox 4 network interface without physical access to KVM

Tags: networking, network-programming, vps, kvm, proxmox

I am running proxmox 4 with around 10 KVM and 14LXC.

I can configure ips and network from web GUI for LXC container.

I want to configure the Network interface For KVM without accessing the VM.

Is is possible to configure Network interface without accessing the VM.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't configure the IP address in proxmox for a KVM vm (only for the lxc container you can define the ip address). For a KVM vm you can configure if the network connection is in Bridged mode or NAT.

For LXC containers you can use the **pct** command to set network for the container. More info about that on the Proxmox WIKI (scroll down to the Network section) - https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Linux_Container

What you could do for KVM would be to use a local DHCP server (you can install one on your proxmox if you want (**apt-get install isc-dhcp-server**). You have to define an ip address pool that will be assigned to your vms by the dhcp server.

Then configure the kvm machine using: **qm** command

```
qm set vmid options
```

From a man qm you discover this:

```
  -net[n] [model=]<enum> [,bridge=<bridge>] [,firewall=<1|0>] [,link_down=<1|0>] [,macaddr=<XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX>] [,queues=<integer>]
       [,rate=<number>] [,tag=<integer>] [,trunks=<vlanid[;vlanid...]>] [,<model>=<macaddr>]
```

So basically you can define the network for your kvm vm, say if it's bridged, set a specific mac address for that card.

If you want to add a specific ip to that vm you can do it based on its mac address (you have to configure in the dhcp server that a specific ip address is assigned to the desired mac address).